# Replace /**/ in Unix with an empty space

Tags: regex, unix, replace, sed, awk

I wanted to replace `/**/` across all files in a folder. I tried:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/\/**\///g;' *.java
```

But got an error: `Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m//** <-- HERE // at -e line 1.`

Same thing with:

```
sed 's/\/**\///g;'
```

I need to basically replace `/**/` with an empty space.

Comment: This `perlfaq6` entry on [how to strip C-style comments](http://search.cpan.org/~dapm/perl-5.14.4/pod/perlfaq6.pod#How_do_I_use_a_regular_expression_to_strip_C-style_comments_from_a_file?) might prove useful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape the asterisks as well. To preserve readability, you may want to use other delimiters as well:

```
sed "s#/\*\*/##g"
```

Comment: I think you have 1 extra `|`

Comment: I wouldn't even propose the first version - hard to read "saw tooth". Btw I like commas or hashes as delimiters when not using slashes

Comment: @Bohemian: The hashes do look nicer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `*` within `[]`:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's#/[*]{2}/# #g;' *.java
```

Alternatively, you can make use of [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) operator:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's#\Q/**/\Q# #g;' *.java
```

which escapes all ASCII characters not matching `/[A-Za-z_0-9]/`.